# SMStextmesage background service async

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

The following code will work for CLICK event handler but i cant let it send automatically

```
 async void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SmsDevice smsDevice2 = (SmsDevice)await SmsDevice.GetDefaultAsync();

        // Create a text message - Set destination number and message text
        SmsTextMessage msg = new SmsTextMessage();
        msg.To = "12345678";
        msg.Body = "xxxx";

        // Send the message asynchronously
        await smsDevice2.SendMessageAsync(msg);


    }
```

This wont work (background service)

```
  async void DisplayToastAsync(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance, ManualResetEvent manualEventWaiter)
    {
        SmsDevice smsDevice2 = (SmsDevice)await SmsDevice.GetDefaultAsync();
        // Create a text message - Set destination number and message text
        SmsTextMessage msg = new SmsTextMessage();
        msg.To = "12345678";
        msg.Body = "xxx";

        // Send the message asynchronously
        await smsDevice2.SendMessageAsync(msg);
```

}

Anyone know why? and how can i fix it?

Comment: What do you mean, it won't work? What *does* it do? Does it throw and exception, or what?

Comment: Nothing thrown.i know it sounds weird but , other codes in DisplaytoastAsync does get executed

Answer (score 1):

I was experimenting and I found that you do need to fill in the "From" field (a copy of `SmsDevice.AccountPhoneNumber`).

Having said that, I still get a so called 'generic error', but at least it isn't a 'parameter error'.

If you're interested, my generic error is 0x80548212.

Also - I'm guessing you already did this (or I think you'd get a null sms device )- but you need to make the app as being able to do text messaging in the manifest.

Further info - that Generic Error was that my SIM was enabled for Data only.  Once swapped out for a SIM that included SMS, the code worked fine.